# Can Node.js continue running process after user closes the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am logging some analytics data based on people clicking on my site. When a person clicks on something, it sends a call to my node application via an ajax call, but if what they clicked is an external link, the original request gets cancelled since they leave the site. Is there a good way for node to process the request even after the client has disconnected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely wouldn't matter if the running process does not need to write things to the response.
Even then, it probably doesn't matter anyway if you  do something like

1. User submits request, you respond "thanx, the job was started".  Before you respond, asynchronously execute the job (not hard given that node.js code *should* be asynchronous to begin with).
2. Job puts data in some table or file or nosql store.
3. User can go to a different url to see a list of jobs and their states (started, running, complete) and view results.

Comment: Looking at my node.js code, I do wait to send a response back after my data is stored in the db. I will try sending the response back immediately and see it that helps.

Comment: @clint -- yes but make sure to start the data processing *asynchronously*.  If you are unsure how to do that, update your question with the details of your process and what you tried, or just start a new question

Comment: It is most definitely an asynchronous call to store my data in the database. It's hard to not make it async in node :-) I think the problem is perhaps that the client ajax call isn't even making it to node sometimes before the browser cuts it off. I will do more testing and get back.